# Adaptively sized delimiters that don't go beyond the size of \bigl and \bigr

Tags: amsmath, delimiters

I would like adaptively sized delimiters, but only up to `\bigl`/`\bigr`-size. That is, there is variation only between ordinary/normal size and one size higher.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}


\begin{document}

\(\abs{M} + \abs{M^2} + \abs{\abs{M^2}^2}\)
  % the outer delimiters on the right are of the size of \Bigl and \Bigr
  % (i.e. the next larger size after that of \bigl and \bigr)

\(\abs{M} + \abs{M^2} + \bigl\lvert \abs{M^2}^2 \bigr\rvert\)

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this? For the above code, this would amount to defining `\abs` in a way that makes the two lines look the same.

(Here the default behavior of `\left` and `\right` (i.e. scaling to `\bigl`/`\bigr`) looks better, but I'm trying to keep the example short; I'd have to load a lot of packages to demonstrate my personal need. Also, a simple reason is that I need to embed certain formulas in paragraph text.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following example measures the formula inside `\abs` with `\left`/`\right` and with `\bigl`/`\bigr`. If the version `\left`/`\right` is larger, then the version with `\bigl`/`\bigr` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\abs}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@abs{#1}%
}
% Version with the horizontal spacing of `\left` and `\right` in all cases:
% \newcommand*{\abs}[1]{%
%   \mathinner{\mathpalette\@abs{#1}}%
% }
\newcommand*{\@abs}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\mleft\lvert#2\mright\rvert$}%
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1\bigl\lvert#2\bigr\rvert$}%   
  \ifdim\wd0>\wd2 %
    \bigl\lvert#2\bigr\rvert
  \else
    \ifdim\ht0>\ht2 %
      \bigl\lvert#2\bigr\rvert
    \else
      \ifdim\dp0>\dp2 %
        \bigl\lvert#2\bigr\rvert
      \else
        \mleft\lvert#2\mright\rvert
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(\abs{M} + \abs{M^2} + \abs{\abs{M^2}^2}\)

\(\abs{M} + \abs{M^2} + \bigl\lvert \abs{M^2}^2 \bigr\rvert\)

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- Instead of `\left`/`\right` macros `\mleft`/`\mright` of package `mleftright` are used to avoid the additional spacing of `\left`/`\right`.
- The method is not "bulletproof". It makes the following assumption. If the delimiters, picked by `\mleft` and `\mright`, are larger than the version with `\bigl` and `\bigr`, then this case can only be detected, if at least either the width, height or depth increases. For the case that the width remains the same, then the larger delimiters need to be slightly larger than the formula, otherwise the formula would hide the height/depth of the delimiters. I haven't analyzed all resizeable delimiters, but I think, usually the width of the delimiter will become larger that is easily detected.

### Second approach

This approach implements the algorithm of minimal delimiter size according to "The TeXbook" by D. E. Knuth, "Appendix G: Generating Boxes from Formulas", item "19.":

> If the math list begins and ends with boundary items, compute the
>   maximum height *h* and depth *d* of the boxes in the translation of
>   the math list [...]. Let *a* = *σ*<sub>22</sub> be the axis
>   height, and let *δ* = max(*h*-*a*, *d*+*a*) be the
>   amount by which the formula extends away from the axis. Replace the
>   boundary items by delimiters whose height plus depth is at least
>   max(⎣δ/500⎦*f*, 2δ-*l*), where *f* is the
>   `\delimiterfactor` and *l* is the `\delimitershortfall`. [...]

It can deal correctly with an expression like `M^{2^{2^2}}_{f_{f_f}}`, which trips up the first approach by violating its assumption about delimiter dimensions.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\abs}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@abs{#1}%
}
% Version with the horizontal spacing of `\left` and `\right` in all cases:
% \newcommand*{\abs}[1]{%
%   \mathinner{\mathpalette\@abs{#1}}%
% }
\newcommand*{\@abs}[2]{%
  % a := math axis height -> \dimen0
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \dimen0=\ht0 %
  % formula without delimiters -> \box0
  % h := height of formula -> \ht0
  % d := depth of formula -> \dp0
  \sbox0{$#1#2$}%
  % delta := max(h-a, d+a) -> \dimen2
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\ht0-\dimen0\relax
  \dimen4=\dimexpr\dp0+\dimen0\relax
  \ifdim\dimen4>\dimen2 %
    \dimen2=\dimen4 %
  \fi
  % delimiter's total height >= max(floor(delta/500)*f, 2*delta - l)
  %   -> \dimen4
  % f := \delimiterfactor
  % l := \delimitershortfall
  \dimen4 = \dimen2 %
  \divide\dimen4 by 500 %
  \dimen4=\delimiterfactor\dimen4 %
  \dimen6=\dimexpr 2\dimen2 - \delimitershortfall\relax
  \ifdim\dimen6>\dimen4 %
    \dimen4=\dimen6 %
  \fi
  % formula with \bigl/\bigr
  \sbox0{$#1\bigl\lvert\bigr\rvert$}%
  % comparison: Use \mleft/\mright, if \bigl/\bigr is larger than needed
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax>\dimen4 %
    % Case 1: \bigl/\bigr is larger than the minimum needed height.
    %   This means that either (\lvert,\rvert) or (\bigl\lvert,\bigr\rvert)
    %   provide the smallest delimiter size that meet the minimum height requirement.
    %   Consequently we can have \mleft/\mright choose (they won't pick anything
    %   larger than \bigl/\bigr).
    \mleft\lvert#2\mright\rvert
  \else
    % Case 2: \bigl/\bigr is exactly right or smaller than the required minimum height
    %   => use \bigl\bigr
    \bigl\lvert#2\bigr\rvert
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(\abs{M} + \abs{M^2} + \abs{\abs{M^2}^2}\)

\(\abs{M} + \abs{M^2} + \bigl\lvert \abs{M^2}^2 \bigr\rvert\)

\( \abs{M^{2^{2^2}}_{f_{f_f}}} \)

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Can I replace (`\mleft`, `\mright`) by (`\left`, `\right`) in your code, or are there caveats I need to know about if I do this? Perhaps I should ask a different question: I understand that `mleftright` makes sure to not generate the `mathinner` character class (or should I write "`mathinner` spacing"?). I would like any "size-limited `\left` and `\right`" functionality to behave like what I ordinarily do in my documents. When exactly will (La)TeX normally generate `mathinner`? Do you have a good pointer so that I can decide about `\mleft`/`\mright` vs `\left`/`\right`?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: A formula with `\left` and `\right` is a `\mathinner` subformula that might be surrounded by additional space depending on the context. However, `\bigl` and `\bigr` do not have these special treatment. Therefore I have used `\mleft` and `\mright` so that `\abs` has a consistent spacing that does not change if the height/depth of the formula is larger or smaller. But feel free to add `\mathinner` if you want to have the additional spacing.

Comment: Thanks, this is a lucid explanation. Do I understand it correctly that achieving consistent `mathinner` classification would be achieved by doing the following two things? (1) replacing the 4 occurrences of `\bigl\lvert#2\bigr\rvert` by `\mathinner{\bigl\lvert#2\bigr\rvert}` and (2) replacing the 2 occurrences of `\mleft\lvert#2\mright\rvert` by `\left\lvert#2\right\rvert`.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Yes, this should do it and you won't need package `mleftright`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why `\bigl`/`\bigr` etc. don't automatically get `\mathinner` treatment?

Comment: I've found a case that your code doesn't yet handle: `M^{2^{2^2}}_{f_{f_f}}`. (e.g. `\(\bigl\lvert M^{2^{2^2}}_{f_{f_f}} \bigr\rvert  +  \abs{M^{2^{2^2}}_{f_{f_f}}}\)`)

Comment: @LoverofStructure: You can use a single `\bigl`/`\bigr` or even a reversed order. Thus there is not a clear definition of something that could be put in `\mathinner`.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: The formula `M^{2^{2^2}}_{f_{f_f}}` has the same dimensions in `\textstyle` and even reversed widths in `\scriptscriptstyle`. This is the limitation of this approach. I have an idea for another, but currently no time. Thus the implementation has to wait a little.

Comment: About your reply regarding `\mathinner`: "... while `\left` and `\right` can never be used in unpaired fashion" (we know this, but this info will help others).

Comment: About your reply regarding a different approach to answering the original question: A simple way might be to simply measure the height and depth of the subformula and compare it with the height and depth or ordinary-sized `\lvert`/`\rvert` and choose according to one's own criteria.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Yes, you always need both `\left` and `\right` in this order. But a delimiter can be invisible by using a dot, e.g. `\right.`. In this case TeX inserts the horizontal space `\nulldelimiterspace`. Default is `1.2pt` in LaTeX.

Comment: Did you stylistically mean `\dimen0=\ht0 %` instead of `\dimen0=\ht0` in your second approach?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Yes, I have added the "stylistic" percent sign. (The space before ends the parsing of the explicit number `0`.)

Comment: Yep; I'm still learning some of these details, but it's great to hear that my understanding of the matter is correct. I called it "stylistic" because your code technically works without it, but I find that I agree with your coding style.